# the_time() returning wrong date/time (way in the future)

Tags: attachments, media, front-end

Within a loop, that otherwise works fine, `the_time()` is giving me a date and time about 25 days and a few hours ahead of the actual date.
For instance, if I post today, it lists it as "April 30th, 2013" (today is April 6th, 2013).

I can't for the life of me figure out why it's doing this.

A couple things: This is on the front-end of my site and I am looping through a users posted attachments (sort of like a front-end media manager). The loop is working fine to grab the thumbnail, the attached post (and it's date), etc but the time of the actual upload of the file is just not right.

That being said, the date/time that lists in the wp-admin section is correct, which is even more confusing...

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Lp00HvBx) of the entire page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I post today, it lists it as April 30th, 2013 (today is April 6th,
> 2013).

## Your using a lowercase t in your [date format string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
t   Number of days in the given month   28 through 31
```

On Line 92:

`echo get_the_time('M-t-y \a\t g:ha' , $id);`

I think you meant to use d or j instead.

Comment: Great catch! That was the issue alright, thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score -2):

If this is on a VPS or a dedicated server, I would advise you take a look at your server's settings and adjust the time accordingly.
PHP gets the time from the system so this might be a simple case of misconfigured time on the server side.

Comment: Always check the code before suggesting configuration settings. 99% of the time the code is wrong.